# Generate custom response in DRF ModelSerializer

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I need some help, I've used `ModelSerializer` in `DRF`, here is the problem:

I want to generate response dynamically, I mean I decide on user's input, so I need to pass request parameter to `ModelSerializer`, then decide if my condition is established, generate fields, otherwise generate some other fields.

Something like this:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        if request.SOME_CONDITION: 
            fields = ('id', 'name_fa', 'name_en', 'price')
        else: 
            fields = ('description', 'image_path_absolute', 'publisher')
```

I've googled and got that I can pass parameters using `context` to serializers, but in serializer I need to get parameters via `self` object.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay

I found it.

We need to override `__init__()` method of serializer class, then get params using context, exclude unwanted fields, finally call super class.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'context' in kwargs:
        context = kwargs.get('context')
        if 'user' in context:
            if SOME_CONDITION:
                super(AlbumSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.fields.pop(key)
                pass
    super(AlbumSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```